# mySQL InnoDB Table doesn't work on 1and1 server, does on localhost

Tags: php, mysqli, innodb, prepared-statement, myisam

**EDIT**

I changed the table to MyISAM, and it worked.  Anyone know why InnoDB wouldn't work, and if there's a way to "enable" it?

---

Basically, I insert a row, **am able to reference the new id** via $mysqli->insert_id, select the row, translate it into an associative array, and return it.  Right after that, in another function, I try to select it and it does not exist.  It also does not exist in the database.  Update simply does not update, and delete simply does not delete (although when i say $stmt->affected_rows, it returns > 0).

One table (news) modifies without a problem, but another table (products), which utilizes the same code (only it has it's own table name and field values) does not.

The function is this:

```
function addNews($title, $message) {
        $mysqli = open_mysqli();

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO news(title, message) VALUES (?,?)")) {
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $title, $message);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();

            $id = $mysqli->insert_id;
            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=? LIMIT 1")) {
                $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
                $stmt->execute();

                $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
                while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) { 
                    $params[] = &$row[$field->name]; 
                } 
                call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);                
                while ($stmt->fetch()) { 
                    foreach($row as $key => $val) { 
                        $c[$key] = $val; 
                    } 
                    $results[] = $c; 
                } 

                $stmt->close();
                $mysqli->close();

                if(isset($results) && $results) {
                    return sqlResultObj(true, $results[0]);
                } else {
                    return sqlErrorObj('No news with id '.$id);
                }
            }
        } else {
            return sqlErrorObj('Problem adding news.');
        }
    }
```

The only difference between the tables, besides the fields themselves, is that product is an InnoDB Storage Engine and has other tables referencing it as their foreign key, while news is MyISAM, and does not.

Like I said, this works perfectly on my local WAMP server (running Apache 2.2.11, PHP 5.3.0, MySQL 5.1.36) but it presents the above problems on my 1and1 server (PHP 5, MySQL 5, and I have the USA 1&1 Beginner Package Linux_WS... not sure which version of Apache or where to find it).  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps your mysql user account does not have write privileges?

Comment: No - the news table is using the same account and is in the same database.  I would assume that that is not the problem.

Comment: You have problem when inserting to news or product? If product put the code you used to work with Product. Your code is which you used to news right?

Comment: News works, Product does not.  The code is literally the same exact thing, except the queries are "INSERT INTO product(name, description, thumbnail, createdate, filedirectory, active) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)" and "SELECT * FROM product WHERE id=? LIMIT 1"

The problem is not the query - it works just fine on my localhost.  I'm thinking it's something to do with InnoDB and 1and1?

Comment: Do you have error_reporting and display_errors enabled? Do you get any error message?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the status of the InnoDB engine?

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

You may have already done this, but check the permissions you have for the user credentials. Make sure MySQL is set to allow insert and delete with the user credentials you are using and the host setting is correct (i.e. %, localhost, etc.)

Comment: MySQL said:
#1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation

Comment: Sounds like there may be a permission issue. You will need to contact 1and1 and ask them for support.